# Spring websockets, NettyTcpClient - Failed to connect

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, netty

I'm receiving the following message every 5 seconds:

```
[WEBAPP] 02 Nov 2014 17:55:43  INFO NettyTcpClient - Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:61613. Attempting reconnect in 5000ms.
```

I'm using spring 4 with stomp and activemq

any ideas why that happnes?

BTW: the webapp runs on tomcat #1 while my activemq broker is located @ a different machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the URL was wrong.

I fixed it with the following code:

```
 config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic","/queue/").setRelayHost(THE_RIGHT_URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I slved this problem with this configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ActiveMQProperties.class)
public class WebSocketConfig extends WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport {

    @Autowired
    private ActiveMQProperties activeMQProperties;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/notify").setRelayHost("192.168.99.100")
        .setSystemLogin("admin").setSystemPasscode("admin");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/createBookJob").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

In the my use case I'm experiencing whe use activeMq as STOMP provider ina docker image.

`setRelayHost("192.168.99.100")` was usefull becouse 192.168.99.100 is the defualt ip that I use

.setClientLogin("admin").setClientPasscode("admin")
    .setSystemLogin("admin").setSystemPasscode("admin");

becouse in active mq the default users has admin admin as user and password

it works for me

I hope that this can help you

Comment: Just for chiarification I use Spring MVC 4 for the web socket